# É possível criar aplicativos mobile (.apk e .obb) usando electron?

Tags: android, electron

Gostaria de saber se é possível gerar executáveis que rodem no ambiente mobile (Android  iOS, Windows Phone 
etc) através do electron, isto é possível?

Answer (score 2):

Não, isso não é possível. O electron é uma ferramenta para criação de aplicações Desktop exclusivamente. Para mobile há outras soluções similares, como o Phonegap.